# Changing size of points in R

Tags: r, graphics, plot

I would like to make a scatter plot using R base graphics, though I can use ggplot if it is necesary.  I have a data frame containing the x and y coordinates, and also two other covariates, call them a and b.  I would like the size of each point to vary with a (high values of a -> larger points) and the brightness/solidity of each point to vary with b (so that those points with low enough b are practically invisiable).  Does anyone have any advice on how to do this?  The documentation for R graphics seems comprehensive, but so general and high-level that I scarcely know where to begin.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

The sample line below shows how to use size and alpha simultaneously in a plot

```
plot(1:6, sample(6), cex = sample(6)/2, col = rgb(0,0,0, sample(6)/6), pch = 19)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `cex` parameter is a quick and dirty way of changing the size of the plotting characters, but you do need to work quite a bit if you want to have an informative scale etc. `symbols()` is one way to do this more accurately with base graphics.

Using some dummy data, here is one plot using `cex` and one using `symbols()`:

```
## dummy data first
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(X = rnorm(10), Y = rnorm(10,2,2), a = runif(10), b = runif(10))

## plot using cex
plot(Y ~ X, data = dat, cex = 10 * a)

## plot using symbols()
with(dat, symbols(X, Y, circles = a))
```

You can colour the points using the `col` parameter in the `cex` example or using the `fg` argument in the symbols case. The trick will be get an appropriate scale. In our dummy data, `b` is on the interval (0,1], so our scale might be to break this into 5 categories and use one of five plotting colours.

```
## Eg using heat.colors(5)
cut.pts <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)
cuts <- with(dat, cut(b, cut.pts))
with(dat, symbols(X, Y, circles = a, bg = heat.colors(5)[cuts]))
```

As you see, it is important to choose appropriate colours though as here, one colour is the same as the background.

Doing this with `ggplot2` is likely going to be much simpler as all the heavy lifting has already been done for you by Hadley Wickham.

```
## Eg using ggplot
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(X, Y, colour = b, size = a))
p + geom_point()
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

This comes up often in R-help such as [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-May/161175.html).  Basically, `cex` will be the argument of interest for changing the size of the points.  For changing color of the points I would suggest something like setting `col=heat.colors()`  or making your own color list and define as a factor before plotting.